# A specific coset decomposition of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, lie-groups, matrix-decomposition, general-linear-group

I am reading an old paper [1] where they introduce a specific decomposition of a complex, invertible matrix. There is no proof, so I am trying to come up with one. The claim goes as follows:

Let $\mathbf{M} \in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ be an element of the general linear group (i.e. an $n \times n$, complex, invertible matrix). Then $\mathbf{M}$ can be written as
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
   \mathbf{M} = \exp(\mathbf{m}) = \exp(\mathbf{m'}) \exp(\mathbf{m''})
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{m} \in \mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is an element of the general linear Lie algebra (i.e. an $n \times n$, complex matrix). The matrices $\mathbf{m}'$ and $\mathbf{m}''$ are $n \times n$, complex, block-matrices of the form
\begin{align}
   \mathbf{m}' &= 
   \begin{bmatrix}
   \mathbf{0}'_{00} & \mathbf{m}'_{01} & \mathbf{m}'_{02} \\
   \mathbf{m}'_{10} & \mathbf{0}'_{11} & \mathbf{m}'_{12} \\
   \mathbf{m}'_{20} & \mathbf{m}'_{21} & \mathbf{0}'_{22}
   \end{bmatrix}\tag{2} \\
   \mathbf{m}'' &=
   \begin{bmatrix}
   \mathbf{m}''_{00} & \mathbf{0}''_{01} & \mathbf{0}''_{02} \\
   \mathbf{0}''_{10} & \mathbf{m}''_{11} & \mathbf{0}''_{12} \\
   \mathbf{0}''_{20} & \mathbf{0}''_{21} & \mathbf{m}''_{22}
   \end{bmatrix} \tag{3}.
\end{align}
The diagonal blocks are square and of matching dimensions ($\mathbf{0}'_{00}$ has the same dimensions as $\mathbf{m}''_{00}$, say $n_0 \times n_0$, and so on). In essence, $\mathbf{m}'$ has zero blocks on the diagonal while $\mathbf{m}''$ is block-diagonal. I realize that the number of blocks is not essential for the problem; I'm using three by three blocks for illustration.

I know that the exponential map of the general linear group is surjective, meaning that for every $\mathbf{M} \in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ there exists some $\mathbf{m} \in \mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $\mathbf{M} = \exp(\mathbf{m})$. So far so good. I can also see that block-diagonal matrices of the form (3) form a Lie algebra, say $\mathfrak{b}_n(\mathbb{C})$, which generates a Lie group of $n \times n$, complex, invertible, block-diagonal matrices, say $\mathrm{B}_n(\mathbb{C})$, which is a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. The paper suggests that the factorisation in (1) should be viewed as a coset decomposition. As far as I understand, the group $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is the union of the left cosets
\begin{equation}
   g \, \mathrm{B}_n(\mathbb{C}) = \{ g \, h \;|\; h \in \mathrm{B}_n(\mathbb{C}) \},
   \quad g \in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C}).
\end{equation}
I also know that some cosets may be identical so one doesn't need all cosets in order get the whole group (so to speak). What I don't understand is the specific form of the matrix $\mathbf{m}'$.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[1] J. Linderberg and Y. Öhrn, Int. J. Quantum Chem. **12**(1), 161–191 (1977). *State vectors and propagators in many-electron theory. A unified approach.*

Comment: More generally, we can ask if (or when) a Lie group $G$ is a "knit product" of exponentiated complementary vector subspaces of the lie algebra $\frak g$.

Comment: @runway44: This is a nice generalisation of the question. I suppose it would also be useful to answer the slightly less general question where one of the vector subspaces of $\mathfrak{g}$ is also a subalgebra.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. And maybe the subspaces are orthogonal with respect to the Killing form.